# how to freeze values of column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a scattered plot of users usage across Month.
whenever I filter users only relevant values appear i.e if user A has used a report in Jan Feb mar and Sept only those values appear on columns tab.
I want all the months displayed on the column and then a scatter plot on it(row being Number of Records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to **Analysis**/**Table Layout** and selecting **Show Empty Columns**.

**Note**: If you're using a secondary data source, [this functionality is disabled](http://community.tableau.com/ideas/2921).

Comment: its greyed out...:( I cannot choose that option.

Comment: I took a shot. Are you using a secondary data source on the worksheet?

Comment: Aha. Fun fact about Tableau, [this functionality doesn't work when you're using a secondary data source](http://community.tableau.com/ideas/2921).

Comment: I searched the forums for workarounds, but no one seems to have one. Here's hoping that Tableau super genius [@AlexBlakemore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441979/alex-blakemore) comes in with a brilliant solution that no one's ever dared to dream of, but as far as I can tell, you're stuck.

Comment: You could try adding zero'd rows to your data source. Your user used a report in Jan, Feb, Mar, and Sep, so those are the only rows you have. You could add rows to your data source for the other eight months with zeroes and NULLs for all your measures. I'm not promising that will work, and it frankly sounds like a tremendous pain, but if it's urgent that you produce this chart, that could be a solution. Note that if that works (again, no promises), `Number of Records` will no longer work. You could add another field to your rows that's `1` if a report was used, `0` otherwise, and `SUM` it up?

Comment: thats a great idea, Ill speak to my DBA tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!